# Useless information in browser's card title while displaying pdf

Tags: moderncv

I'm currently writing Resume using 'moderncv' package. Everything is fine, but when I try to display pdf in e.g. Firefox, the title of card seems like this:

[image]

when my file is called 'Doe_John_Resume.pdf'. Is it possible to display **only** title of file in browser's card and remove useless information?

Necessary tags:

```
\firstname{\vspace{0.4em}John}
\familyname{\vspace{0.4em}Doe}
```

Comment: TBH, using vspace in those macros seems a bad idea, it would be more appropriate to adjust the theme to apply the desired spacings. However you can still save the day by using `\texorpdfstring`

Comment: Ok, but i want to remove 'John Doe - -' part too.

Comment: You can control the title metadata stored in the pdf, but you cannot control what the browser decides to put there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discourage the use of `\vspace` in macros that are just meant to collect data like `\title` etc.
It would be more appropriate to modify the theme to obtain the desired spacing.
However, a quick fix is:

```
\firstname{\texorpdfstring{\vspace{0.4em}John}{John}}
\familyname{\texorpdfstring{\vspace{0.4em}Doe}{Doe}}
```

The macro is offered by the `hyperref` package and produces the first argument when used in a typesetting context and the second when used to produce pdf metadata (e.g. the pdf TOC).

If you want to control the title in the PDF metadata directly,
you can simply use `hyperref`'s facilities, for example:

```
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Whatever},
  pdfauthor={my self and I}
}
```

Comment: Unlucky, \hypersetup doesn't work, even with 'hyperref' package included.

Comment: It's because `moderncv` sets up these parameters at the end of the preamble.
Try wrapping the `\hypersetup` block with `\AtEndPreamble{\hypersetup{...}}`